# Repeating post on Wordpress theme and Thumbnail not Appearing

Tags: php, wordpress, posts, repeat

I need some help trying to figure this out, but currently, when I post a post on the Manhusay Theme on my Wordpress Site, it repeats it 3 times and replaces the other posts. The site is www.pcrmj.com. Here is the script that is currently in there if anyone has any suggestions or ways of correcting this.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="content">

    <div class="postgroup">
        <?php for($i=1;$i<4;$i++) : ?>
        <?php
            $latest = get_option('mahusay_category_' . $i);
            $latcat = (empty($latest)) ? 1 : get_category_by_slug($latest);
            query_posts('showposts=1&cat='.$latcat->cat_ID);
        ?>

        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <div class="post indexpost" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
            <?php
                $customfields = get_post_custom();
                $scrp = get_bloginfo('wpurl') . '/tt-scripts/timthumb.php?';
                if (empty($customfields['paddimage'][0])) {
                    $imgpath = $scrp . 'src=' . get_bloginfo('wpurl') . '/wp-content/themes/mahusay/images/thumbnail.png' . '&amp;w=125&amp;h=125&amp;zc=1';
                } else {
                    $imgpath = $scrp . 'src=' . get_bloginfo('wpurl') .  $customfields['paddimage'][0] . '&amp;w=125&amp;h=125&amp;zc=1';
                }
            ?>
            <div class="title">
                <p>
                    <span class="date"><?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?></span>
                    <span class="nodisplay">|</span>
                    <span class="comments"><?php comments_popup_link('No Comments', '1 Comment', '% Comments'); ?></span>
                    <span class="nodisplay">|</span>
                    <span class="categories"><?php echo $latcat->cat_name; ?></span>
                </p>
            </div>
            <img class="header" src="<?php echo $imgpath; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
            <div class="entry">
                <h2 class="title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <?php themefunction_content(400,'');?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endfor; ?>
    </div>


    <div class="extra">
        <div class="box box-popular">
            <h2>Popular</h2>
            <div class="interior">
                <ul>
                <?php akpc_most_popular(5,'<li><span>','</span></li>'); ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box box-recent">
            <h2>Recent</h2>
            <div class="interior">
                <?php themefunction_recent_post(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearer"></div>
    </div>

</div>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Also, Thumbnail.png is not appearing. If anybody can help, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do is after the following line...

```
<?php endfor; ?>
```

Add...

```
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

This resets the query back to what the query for that page should be and will stop any query_posts functions effecting other loops on the page.

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work....do you have any other suggestions? It's still looping.